# VB.NET project properties namespaces vs Imports statement?

Tags: .net, vb.net, namespaces, import

In a VB.NET project, what is the difference between importing a namespace in Project-Properties and using a `Imports [NameSpace]` statement at the start of a file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Imports in the project properties apply to *all* code files.

The `Imports` directive only applies to the class it is declared in.

From [How to: Add or Remove Imported Namespaces (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3w4tctcf.aspx) on MSDN:

> Imported namespaces are managed on the References page of the Project Designer. The imports you specify in this dialog box are passed directly to the compiler (/imports) and apply to all files in your project.

Comment: So if you import a namespace for a whole project you don't have to use `Imports [namespace]` in each file?